# how to write test case to toggle the component in react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing

I'm beginner in writing Unit test cases. I want to write test case to toggle a component. I have wrote in this way:

```
test("should toggle the component", ()=> {
const toggleComp = jest.fn();
const isOpen: boolean = false;
const btnEl = screen.getByTestId("button");
fireEvent.click(toggleBtn);
expect(isOpen).toBe(true);
})
```

It is showing **Failed** :

```
expected: true
received: false 

expect(isOpen).toBe(true);
               ^
```

Can anyone help me on this issue? Thanks in advance!

I was expecting the output:

When we click the button then isOpen value should be true otherwise false.

Answer (score 1):

Once you fired `fireEvent.click(btnEl);` event, check again in `screen` toggled component/element been rendered or not

eg :   `expect(screen.getByText(/toggled text/i)).toBeInTheDocument(); or expect(screen. getByTestId("toggledId")).toBeInTheDocument();`

in your scenario there is no correlation with `isOpen` because it's a test case variable

Added few example below

```
import { useState } from "react";

const ToggleButton = () => {
  const [isToggled, setToggle] = useState(false);

  return (
    <button data-testid="toggleButton" onClick={() => setToggle(!isToggled)}>
      {isToggled ? "Toggled" : "Initial"}
    </button>
  );
};

export default ToggleButton;
```

Test Steps

```
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import ToggleButton from "./ToggleButton";

test("Test ToggleButton", async () => {
  render(<ToggleButton />);

  expect(screen.getByText(/Initial/i)).toBeInTheDocument();

  const buttonElment = screen.getByTestId("toggleButton");
  fireEvent.click(buttonElment);

  expect(screen.getByText(/Toggled/i)).toBeInTheDocument();

  fireEvent.click(buttonElment);

  expect(screen.getByText(/Initial/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

as given sample

```
<Button data-testid="toggleButton"  onClick={handleModal}>
    Open modal
</Button>
```

Test case for that

```
test("Test BasicModal", async () => {
  const { queryByText } = render(<BasicModal />);

  const buttonElment = screen.getByTestId("toggleButton");

  fireEvent.click(buttonElment);

  expect(queryByText(/Text in a modal/i)).toBeVisible();

  expect(queryByText(/est non commodo luctus/i)).toBeVisible();
});
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate and write briefly

Comment: @Natasha_JS I have updated few example steps above

Comment: Thank you writing with an example. can you please hep me  -  instead of **{isToggled ? "Toggled" : "Initial"}** , if there is a modal component [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-glade-4pzv3v) then how do we show as per the above example

Comment: You're welcome wrote a few steps for your button click function